# isomorphism between some Permutation groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

> Let $S_n$ be the Permutation group on ${1,...,n}$ , where $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $S_{n+m}$,where $\sigma\in H$ iff for each $1 \le i \le n \ : \ 1 \le \sigma(i) \le n$  .
>
> Prove that $H$ is isomorphic to $S_n\times S_m$.

My attempt:

Let $\phi(\sigma):H\to S_n\times S_m$ be: $(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$ where :

$\sigma_1(i):[n]\to [n] , \sigma_1(i) = \sigma(i)$

$\sigma_2(j):[m]\to [m] , \sigma_2(j)=\sigma(j)$

How can I prove that it's a bijection?

Or maybe it isn't at all?

Comment: Your notation is ambiguous. By $[n]$, I assume you mean $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and by $[m]$, I assume you mean $\{n+1,n+2,\ldots,n+m\}$?

Comment: As written, your $\sigma_2$ is not well-defined: unless $m=n$, it is certainly possible for $\sigma(j) > m$ for some $j \in [m]$, in which case $\sigma_2$ is not a permutation on $[m]$.  You may have the right idea in mind but it is not expressed accurately.

Comment: @Bungo No.For both I mean $[n]={1,...,n}$ and $[m]={1,...m}$. What I actually meant,is that $\phi$ will "split" $\sigma$ into two permutations,Where for each I look only at the relevant part of $\sigma$.

Comment: @ErickWong See the comment above.

Comment: Assuming that you have shown that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, you can check injectivity by showing that its kernel is trivial. Surjectivity should be easy to show directly. Take an arbitrary element $(\sigma_1, \sigma_2) \in S_n \times S_m$, and show that there is some $\phi \in H$ that maps to that element.

Comment: @ChikChak After your clarifying comment above, my comment is clearly more relevant.  Bungo was assuming that you had already addressed this and were using poor notation, but it appears you haven't.

Comment: @ChikChak Then do you want $\sigma_2(j) = \sigma(j+n)$ instead of $\sigma_2(j) = \sigma(j)$?

Comment: @Bungo I think you want the RHS to be $\sigma(j+n)-n$.

Comment: @ErickWong Oops, you're right.

Comment: @ErickWong so $\sigma_2$ should be $\sigma_2(j)=\sigma(j+n)-n$?

Comment: @ChikChak If you aren't sure, then it isn't what you meant to say: we aren't trying to put words in your mouth.  It's just one of multiple ways to fix what you've written, and you should give some thought towards what is wrong with your original version (and how this could fix it).

Comment: @ErickWong Ok, I understood why my answer is wrong.Can you explain to me the intuition for yours?

Comment: @ChikChak The proposed formula for $\sigma_2$ converts any permutation on $n+1,\ldots,n+m$ into a permutation on $1,\ldots,m$.  It is conjugation of $\sigma$ with a shift of size $n$.  If you understand why your answer is wrong, please update your question which still claims $\phi$ to be a homomorphism.

Comment: @ErickWong edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guess what $[m]$ means, but I presume that your $\sigma$ is

\begin{align} \phi(\sigma)=(\sigma |_{\{1,\cdots,n\}} , \sigma|_{\{{1',\cdots,m'\}}})\end{align}
where we consider $S_{n+m}$ as the permutation group of $\{1,\cdots,n,1',\cdots,m'\}$.

Since $|H|=|S_n \times S_m |$, showing injectivity will be suffice. This follows

\begin{align} \phi(\sigma)=id &\Leftrightarrow \sigma |_{\{1,\cdots,n\}}=id|_{\{1,\cdots,n\}} \,\;\mathrm{and}\;\, \sigma|_{\{{1',\cdots,m'\}}} =id|_{\{1',\cdots,m'\}}\\
&\Leftrightarrow \sigma=id
\end{align}
where $id$ is the identity function on  $\{1,\cdots,n,1',\cdots,m'\}$.

Comment: What do you mean by ${1',...,m'}$?and why does it even shows injectivity?

Comment: @Chikchak // $1', ..., m'$ are just an alias of $n+1 , \cdots , n+m$. I used this notation just for convenience.
For second question, this is because of Pigeonhole principle, stating that for every finite set $A,B$ such that $|A|=|B|$, and a function $f:A\to B$, $f$ is injective if and only if $f$ is surjective.

Comment: What I mean is,why showing what you proved with the $id$ function,proves injectivity?

Comment: @ChikChak Once one knows that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, then injectivity is exactly equivalent to having a trivial kernel.  Are you asking how to see that $\phi$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: @ErickWong is right.

Comment: @ErickWong Ah,I understand it all now.thank you both.